# AngularJS: Can I use one-time binding in ng-pluralize?

Tags: angularjs

<del>I tried this, but it does not work:</del> **This is now implemented in Angular 1.3.4.**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
    <input type="number" ng-model="foo" ng-init="foo=1"><hr>
    Normal binding: <ng-pluralize count="foo" when="{'0': 'zero', '1': 'one', 'other': 'many'}"></ng-pluralize><hr>
    One-time binding: <ng-pluralize count="::foo" when="{'0': 'zero', '1': 'one', 'other': 'many'}"></ng-pluralize>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there another way using `ng-pluralize`?

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/iaFI3p?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blackhole's suggestion works (thank you!)

```
// Blackhole's suggestion, try here: http://plnkr.co/edit/roxHzV?p=preview
<ng-pluralize count="{{ ::foo }}" when="{'0': 'zero', '1': 'one', 'other': 'many'}"></ng-pluralize>
```

I was expecting `count="::foo"` to work so I opened [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10004). Caitp from the Angular team agreed and it's currently planned for Angular 1.3.4.

Comment: "It's currently planned for Angular 1.3.4". Indeed, 1.3.4 is here, and that's now an official feature :).